# Cannot make Aliases and Facades work in Laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel, singleton, alias, facade

I am developing a Laravel package and have a trouble setting up facades/aliases. I.e. I want to have a class for formatting money, so that in the backend and in the views I can just do `Money::format(10)` and have it formatted according to currency configuration.

So, first in main package provider I have registered a HelpersProvider and inside it, I have:

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->singleton(\PathToPackage\Helpers\Money::class, function ($app) {
        return new \PathToPackage\Helpers\Money();
    });
    $this->app->alias(\PathToPackage\Helpers\Money::class, 'money');

}

public function provides()
{

    return [\PathToPackage\Helpers\Money::class, 'money'];

}
```

My Money class is simple:

```
namespace PathToPackage\Helpers;

class Money {

    public static function format($amount) {

        // format and return

    }

}
```

Now if I put just `use Money` in my controller it does not work, so the alias is not working. The singleton works though, if I call the class as `\PathToPackage\Helpers\Money::format()` in the controller it is instantiated only once.

Same in my views - if I call like `{{ Money::format() }}` it doesn't work, but using the full path `{{ \PathToPackage\Helpers\Money::format() }}` it is working.

I also did a facade class, but did not understand where to hook it up in the provider?

```
namespace PathToPackage\Facades\Money;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Money extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'money';
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding it to the config/app.php file?

Comment: If it was in an app that is what I do and it works without issues, but this time I need to make it work within a Laravel Package - I want it to work out of the box, without the user having to do anything after "composer require"

Comment: Even packages need to be linked to laravel somehow. I don't think your package will be so special that doesn't need to be registered in app config, while Artisan, Blade or App itself do.

Comment: Laravel itself takes the config and uses the methods above to register the config into the service container. So using the config is not needed. It is just a matter of supplying the correct parameters and unfortunately the documentation is inconsistent in the examples it has in the service provider section.

Comment: Your facade definition says that the facade is PathToPackage\Facades\Money\Money .
Your facade needs either to be in config/app.php aliases or wherever you use it you have to "use PathToPackage\Facades\Money\Money;"

Comment: If you want to avoid the manual setting of alias in app/config.php have a look at the newer https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#package-discovery with which you can register aliases in your composer.json extra section. In any case, in your current code, you haven't set the facade alias anywhere yet.

Comment: Isn't $this->app->alias() supposed to do this - register an alias of "Money" for the full path? Using composer might be the answer actually... I already use it for automatic provider discovery (so the provider does not have to be registered in the config)... Makes sense to use it for aliases as well.

Comment: I understand it is confusing but you haven't alias of your facade anywhere there, you aliased your helper class.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by adding the alias to "aliases" section of module.json

```
{
    "name": "YourModule",
    "alias": "yourmodule",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [],
    "order": 0,
    "providers": [
        "Modules\\YourModule\\Providers\\YourModuleServiceProvider"
    ],
    "aliases":{
        "money": "PathToPackage\\Facades\\Money\\Money"
    },
    "files": []
}
```